# How to display payment methods on a phtml Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment

How can I display all available payment methods on a phtml via layout file?

I have created a custom payment page and I want to show all available payments method there so user can select one and when he can click continue button, it will continue with selected payment method...

Please guide me how to achieve this with some code snippets or examples.

Thanks.